# How to reduce the downtime while launching a EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks

I am trying to launch a kubernetes cluster over EKS which would have multiple pods in it . Once the worker node has maximum pods on it running then a new node launches and the extra pod launches over the new node.  Launching of a new node takes time and creates a downtime which I want to reduce. Pod disruption budget is one option but I am not sure how to use it with scaling up of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to approach this would be to have your scaling policies pre-defined to scale up at reasonably lower limits. This way, let's say if your server reaches 60% of the capacity and triggers a scale up - you would have enough grace time to not face a downtime (since the first one can handle requests while the second one bootstraps) and allow the the new server to come up.

Comment: Okay this also looks good and probably I would try to implement the same but is there any direct configurational changes which can be done to reduce the downtime like setting a specific value which would launch the machine in 40 to 50 seconds or something like that?

Comment: @Kaustubh No there's no such configuration you can provide. Hopefully you are not providing any bootstrap commands to the server under `user-script`. But it takes what it takes.

Comment: No I am not using any bootstrap commands as such.  Okay, then I have this option to go with. Thankyou for the same, it was very helpful.